# C++ isnan() won't work in an if-statement?

Tags: c++, std, isnan

I am trying to check, if a variable is not a number. I tried to use `std::isnan()` for that.

Here's the code that I thought would work:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstddef>
#include <cmath>

int main()
{
    int num = 1;
    if (std::isnan(num))
    {
        std::cout << num << " is a Number" << std::endl;
    }
    else
    {
        std::cout << num << " is a Number" << std::endl;
    }
}
```

The error it is giving is the following:

> "fpclassify": Ambiguous call of an overloaded function

I can't understand why that won't work as expected, seen on many websites as examples.

Here's also a screenshot of everything:

[image: Screen]

Comment: isnan works on floats or doubles, but it doesn't make any sense on integers which have no concept of NaN.

Comment: @VincentFourmond [`std::isnan()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/math/isnan) is actually overloaded for integral types, and will internally call the `double` overload.

Comment: @VincentFourmond Although, when I read the standard I interpreted it as if there should be overloads that cast to `double` for integral types. That's why I wrote a bug report on MSVC. It affects all functions using `fpclassify`, like `std::signbit` and `std::isnan` etc

Comment: What about [`std::isnan()/4`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/math/isnan)?

Comment: @G.M. Yes and https://eel.is/c++draft/cmath.syn#2.2

Comment: Is that an indication that OP isn't using C++11 ?

Comment: Thank you all. I am using C++ 20

Comment: @VincentFourmond It's just a bug in MSVC - but when discussed at Microsoft's github repo, they labeled it _"LEWG issue needed"_ which makes me think they want to undo that part of the standard. It's still not fixed in VS2022 beta I just noticed.

Comment: @RemyLebeau   I must admit, I have difficulty envisaging many situations in which an integral value, when converted to `double` will produce a value for which `std::isnan()` returns true.    Let alone situations where such a result is *useful*.

Comment: @Peter regardless of what the overloads *return*, the fact is the overloads *exist* and should not be causing an ambiguity error.